# ANE iOS packaging issue

Tags: apache-flex, air, ane

I pretty stuck, building the ANE and running it via sample application.

I've successfully built ANE and added it to sample project, but while running it on the device I'm getting:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:


[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
java.io.IOException: PLIST generation failed due to SAX error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.adobe.air.Plist.newFromString(Plist.java:351)
    at com.adobe.air.Plist.newFromFile(Plist.java:325)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.setSDKVersion(IPAOutputStream.java:1070)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.setPlatformSDKLocation(IPAOutputStream.java:971)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.setDeviceSDKDirectory(IPAPackager.java:187)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseFileAndPathArguments(ADT.java:1423)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseDescriptorAndFileset(ADT.java:1474)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseInput(ADT.java:929)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parsePackage(ADT.java:672)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:570)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:419)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:469)
```

Here is my platformoptions.xml

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
     <sdkVersion>7.1</sdkVersion>
     <linkerOptions>
        <option>-ios_version_min 5.0</option>     
        <option>myLib.a</option>
        <option>-weak_framework Twitter</option>
        <option>-weak_framework MessageUI</option>
        <option>-weak_framework StoreKit</option>
        <option>-framework CoreTelephony</option>                
     </linkerOptions>
```

extension.xml

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1"> 
    <id>com.myCompany.air</id> 
    <versionNumber>0.0.1</versionNumber> 
    <platforms> 
         <platform name="iPhone-ARM">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>myLib.a</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>myANEInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>myANEFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
    </platforms> 
</extension>
```

Comment: aren't you missing </platform>. Also check both files are using encoding='utf-8'

Comment: issue e was solved by removing <finalizer>, dont remember more details